# MySQL Unexpected String Comparison Behavior

Tags: mysql

I have trouble understanding how string comparisons work in MySQL.
(I am using MySQL Community Server version 8.0.14)

I have an elmah_error table and a query that filters rows based on an "application" column.
"application" is defined as a `varchar(60)` column with a collation of `utf8_general_ci`

If I run the query below, I get the following results:

```
SELECT application, COUNT(*) FROM elmah.elmah_error GROUP BY application;

/LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT    3330
/LM/W3SVC/4/ROOT    350
```

This indicates that there are only two distinct values for application, with a total row count of 3,680. Just in case, I've double checked this with the following queries.

```
SELECT DISTINCT application FROM elmah.elmah_error;

/LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT
/LM/W3SVC/4/ROOT
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM elmah.elmah_error;

3680
```

However, if I run the following queries, I do not get the results I expect.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM elmah.elmah_error 
where application = '/LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT';

984


SELECT COUNT(*) FROM elmah.elmah_error 
where application <> '/LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT';

350
```

I would expect the first query to return 3,330, and the two queries to add up to 3,680, but it does not.

However, if I were to run any of the following queries, I get the expected results.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM elmah.elmah_error 
WHERE UPPER(application) = '/LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT';

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM elmah.elmah_error 
WHERE TRIM(application) = '/LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT';

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM elmah.elmah_error 
WHERE application LIKE '%/LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT';

3330
```

Based on the `trim` and `like` variants working, I initially suspected that there might be a hidden character before the '/LM'

However, `SELECT DISTINCT LENGTH(application) FROM elmah.elmah_error` indicates that all values have a length of 16. This, and the results of the `GROUP BY application` and `DISTINCT application` queries seem to suggest invisible characters are probably not the case.

Could anyone please shed light on what's going on here?

Comment: Can you try `SELECT BINARY application, COUNT(*) FROM elmah.elmah_error GROUP BY BINARY application;` ?

Comment: I get the same two rows (count 3,330 and 350) although this time `application` is returned as a blob. According to the MySQL Workbench value viewer, the blob contents are 2f-4c-4d-2f-57-33-53-56-43-2f-33-2f-52-4f-4f-54 and 2f-4c-4d-2f-57-33-53-56-43-2f-34-2f-52-4f-4f-54, respectively.

Comment: and `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM elmah.elmah_error 
where BINARY application = '/LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT';` - or `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM elmah.elmah_error 
where BINARY application = '/LM/W3SVC/4/ROOT';` ? I see no reason those should differ from the `GROUP BY` count.

Comment: The first returns 3,330, the latter returns 350, so adding `BINARY` to the left side seems to return the expected results. Just tried `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM elmah.elmah_error 
WHERE application  = CONVERT(CAST('/LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT' as BINARY) USING utf8mb4)` and that works as expected too, although changing `USING utf8mb4` to `USING utf8mb3`  causes it to return 984 instead.

Comment: Strangely, casting the column side works regardless of whether it's using utf8mb4 or utfmb3, but casting the right side only gives the expected results when using utf8mb4. (`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM elmah.elmah_error 
WHERE CONVERT(CAST('/LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT' as BINARY) USING utf8mb3)  = '/LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT';` )

Comment: I just tried running "Analyze Table" and it marked the table as crashed and returned the following error: `Found key at page 101376 that points to record outside datafile.` Ran myisamchk, and got the following warnings (in addition to the one above): `Size of indexfile is: 107520 Should be: 289792` and `Keypointers and record positions doesn't match`. After using myisamchk to repair the table, all queries (including the ones without `BINARY`, `UPPER`, etc) work as expected.

Comment: Still a little confused by this. I do have an index for the Application column, but before doing "Analyze Table," Explain Plan indicated that the query will do a full table scan.
(After repairing with myisamchk, Explain indicates that the index is being used).
My best guess is that the original queries weren't working properly because it was using an incomplete / corrupt index (and Explain Plan was lying about the full table lookup). 
I don't know how MySQL creates query plans, but maybe the UPPER, BINARY, etc. were forcing a full table scan, causing the correct results to be returned.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the followups. I guess you have your answer now, but the symptoms were hard to diagnose!

Answer (score 1):

I speculate that perhaps your table is using a case insensitive collation.  As a result, the value `/LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT` might have other variants in which not all characters are uppercase.  To test this, try your first aggregation query a case-sensitive collation:

```sql
SELECT application COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM elmah.elmah_error
GROUP BY application COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS;
```

Comment: Does this account for the value of 350 when searching for `application <> '/LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT'`?

Comment: I tried the first aggregation query again using utf8_bin but got the same results. (I'm using MySQL rather than MSSQL)